# Hide files with certain extension in Sublime Text Editor?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

is it possible to hide all the files with certain extension from the sidebar (lateral nav bar) in Sublime Text Editor 3?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Are you talking about the sidebar? For example, if you select **File → Open**  and select a folder, then the folder and its contents are displayed along the left side, allowing you to navigate amongst its contents and sub-directories. If that is the case, then the answer is yes, files can be excluded.

Select **Preferences → Settings – Default** to open a tab called `Preferences.sublime-settings – Default`. This file is read-only, so you'll also need to open **Preferences → Settings – User**. The first time you open your user preferences it will be blank. It (and all Sublime config files) are in the [JSON](http://json.org) format, so you'll need opening and closing curly braces at the beginning and end of the file, respectively:

```json
{

}
```

Activate the default preferences tab and search for `file_exclude_patterns` (which is on line 377 in ST3 build 3083) and also `folder_exclude_patterns` if desired. Copy its contents to your user preferences file, like so:

```json
{
    "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", "*.dylib", "*.ncb", "*.sdf", "*.suo", "*.pdb", "*.idb", ".DS_Store", "*.class", "*.psd", "*.db", "*.sublime-workspace"]
}
```

and feel free to add your own customizations. Please note that there is no comma (`,`) after the closing square bracket, as in this example this is the only customized preference. If you have multiple ones (changing fonts, window options, themes, or whatever) you'll need a comma after each item except the last one (trailing commas are illegal JSON):

```json
{
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
    "word_wrap": true,
    "wrap_width": 0
}
```

Comment: It's probably simpler to just say: the settings files are written in JSON.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh, it was hiding the files I needed. Ahahhahahgghghghghghhg . . . cries

Comment: Thanks - just made my development experience a whole lot better :)

Comment: @Matt I added a reference to the folder pattern because this shows up fairly high in a search I did about them.

Comment: is there any plugin can switch the pattern?

Comment: @Elaine yes, plugins can alter the pattern string, you can do so manually by editing the Preferences, you can use language-specific settings, or [projects](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/projects.html) with different values defined within them.

Comment: You can also add this for a directory: e.g. `"folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".git", ".hg", "CVS", "__pycache__"],
`

Answer (score 136):

You can also set them up per project and ignore folders, in your `.sublime-project` file, e.g.:

```json
{
    "folders": [{
        "path": ".",
        "folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", "._d", ".metadata", ".settings"],
        "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", ".project"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Very useful customizing file extensions hided per project.

Comment: You can also use "binary_file_patterns" to hide the folder/files in search, but still see it in the sidebar.

Comment: For anyone else wondering how to create this file, in the top menu go to `Project > Save Project As` and you can then paste this into that file and it works. Creating your own file with `touch` won't work the same :)

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to figure out how to hide all the .js files inside of my project's dist folder, but not .js files anywhere else :) first time using the `.sublime-project`

Comment: to hide all dot files in sublime, use `".*"` within 'folder_exclude_patterns"