# How to hide files with .xml extension in Sublime/MavensMate

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632108/hide-files-with-certain-extension-in-sublime-text-editor) instructions but no avail

I have open the .project file and added this:

> "file_exclude_patterns": ["*-meta.xml"],

but I still see the .xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I able to find out finally by following this:

[image]