# Angular 2 app folder turns into chaos by automatic js-file creation

Tags: typescript, angular

I am starting with Angular, and it seems to be indeed very good.

Before I can proceed with more vigor though, I have this tiny issue that is nagging me. Whenever I save a new .ts file a .js and a .js.map is created directly. As a consequence my app folder is becoming pretty unreadable.

Of course I could create sub-directories, but I understood from a tutorial that all these extra created files needn't be there.

How does one that?

Comment: You can exclude that files from project. Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: I am using Sublime Text 3. Thing is, one tutorial didn't show them in ST3 but the Tour of Heroes and the quick start setup from there site does.

Comment: in tutorial, teacher must have configured Sublime to hide `*.js` and `*.js.map` files. [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632108/hide-files-with-certain-extension-in-sublime-text-editor)

Comment: It is possible to config ng 2 such that it doesn't do this. Does anyone has got an idea for how to do this?