# Hide files with certain extension from specific folder in Sublime Text Editor?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is it possible to hide all the files with certain extension from `some specific folder` in your project directory in sublime text editor 3.

I have found another related [stackover-flow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632108/hide-files-with-certain-extension-in-sublime-text-editor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from the [documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#projects), but you can specify folders in the `file_exclude_patterns` setting in your project file.

Example:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "some_folder_path",
            "file_exclude_patterns": ["messages/*.md"]
        }
    ]
}
```

would exclude all files with a markdown extension (`.md`) from the messages folder, leaving all other `.md` files to be included in the project, for example `some_folder_path/readme.md`.

Note that the above could exclude files in a descendant of the project root, so you may want to prefix the project root dir in your setting:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "some_folder_path",
            "file_exclude_patterns": ["some_folder_path/messages/*.md"]
        }
    ]
}
```

otherwise, `some_folder_path/some_other_folder/messages/*.md` would also be affected, because Sublime Text doesn't constrain the patterns to the project root automatically.

Comment: OK. So for example my target file path is  ""/home/adil/Code/AngularJS.2/mezino-doctor-app/app/file.js.map"".  I am adding this in my sublime user settings, but its not working ........ "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/home/adil/Code/AngularJS.2/mezino-doctor-app",
            "file_exclude_patterns": ["app/*.js", "app/*.js.map"]
        }
    ]

Comment: this needs to go in your project settings - `Project menu -> Edit Project`

Comment: Edit Project is disabled

Comment: you need to save it first, `Project -> Save Project As...`