# Sublime: How to remove .js.map/.js files of .ts files in sublime text

Tags: typescript, sublimetext2

I am using Angular 2 and typescript and I'm not sure what I clicked, but all my .ts files got additional .js.map/.js files created. Do anyone know how to remove these files?

When I'm opening the folder, it seems like it's trying to index the files...I'm not sure what is causing it (see image below).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> compiles `.ts` files into their respective `.js` and `.js.map` files.

If you are using git for version control, and don't have any other untracked files added, you can run:

`git clean -fd` which will remove all untracked files

Comment: Just to complement, in case you have created new files that you don't want to be deleted by running `git clean -fd`, then first use `git add ...` to add them one by one, then `git clean -fd`, and then `git reset`.

Answer (score 2):

Those are files generated by the Typescript compiler.  If you want to hide them, you can add a property to the user config `"file_exclude_patterns"` with a value of an array of patterns to exclude.  You can can `"*.js"` and `"*.map.js"` to exclude those file extensions.

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632108/hide-files-with-certain-extension-in-sublime-text-editor)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to undo what I might have clicked? I don't want to exclude all the *.js files as there are certain files in the folder that are just *.js files.

Comment: No that's what it's supposed to do.  The TS Compiler transpiles the TS files into JS files (and associated source maps if you have that option enabled in the tsconfig.json file)

Comment: I see! Now, I'm experiencing issue with opening a folder of files in sublime. It wouldn't open the folder...but would run something that says..."added folders...[some path]". If I try to open an individual file in sublime it would open. Do you know what might be the issue?

Comment: No I'm not actually familiar with Sublime, never used it, so I'm not sure what it's trying to do, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can `cd` into your `src` folder of your project and safely run

`find . -name "*.js*" -type f`

which will find all of your `.js` and `.js.map` files. Scan through this list and double check to make sure you aren't deleting anything important.

Once you feel good about deleting all those files, run

`find . -name "*.js*" -type f -delete`

which will actually delete the files.

Comment: I then added a User key-binding to Sublime to overwrite "ctrl + b" using this [link](http://brendankemp.com/essays/how-to-add-a-shortcut-for-any-command-in-sublime-text/).

Answer (score 0):

You probably pressed "ctrl + b" which compiles the .ts to then show you the errors in the code.

So the solution is... delete them manually and never press "ctrl + b" again D =

Or change that shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

this just happen to me, because accidentally click ctrl + b to make typescript plugin on sublime text 3 compile all ts to js. To remove all unnecessary js and map file, try this on your src folder (with cmd)
**Windows**

```
del /s *.js

del /s *.map
```

**Mac**

```
find . -name '*.js' -delete

find . -name '*.map' -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove all the `.js` and `.js.map` files which have an associated `.ts` with a python script you can use:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Requires at least Python 3.5+

import os
from pathlib import Path

def clean_ts( ts_file_path ):
    [base_name, ext] = os.path.splitext(ts_file_path)
    if ext != ".ts":
        return
    js_name = base_name + ".js"
    jsmap_name = base_name + ".js.map"
    if os.path.exists(js_name):
        os.remove(js_name)
        print("Delete:\n\t{}".format(js_name))
    if os.path.exists(jsmap_name):
        os.remove(jsmap_name)
        print("Delete:\n\t{}".format(jsmap_name))

pathlist = Path(os.getcwd()).glob('**/*.ts')
for path in pathlist:
    # because path is object not string
    if "node_modules" in str(path):
        continue
    clean_ts(str(path))
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is update the flag `sourceMap:false` in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "scripts/**/*"
  ]
}
```