# How to hide conditionally a file in the folder pane in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there a way to conditionally exclude a file from the folder view in Sublime Text?

I am aware of hiding files using this method described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17635523/2512022

But I am wondering if it is possible to hide file conditionally when another file exists. For example, I only want to hide a .js file if there is another file with the same basename but has the extension ".ts"?

I think you can do something like this in Visual Studio Code.